# Derivation in ray optics

Tags: optics, reflection, refraction, geometric-optics

**How to derive the formula for magnification in spherical mirrors and thin spherical lenses?**

I already know the relationship between image distance (v), object distance (u) and focal length (f), in both the cases.

I also know the formulas for magnification (m) in both the cases, but i don't know how to derive them (for both the cases- spherical mirrors and spherical thin lenses).

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

For real pictures you know $s_1/s_2=S_1/S_2$
s beging the distances, S the sizes of object and picture Of cause magnification is the ratio of picture size to object size.

Comment: Yes i do know this formula. But i want know how to relate this formula with distance of the object from the mirror (u) and distance of image from the mirror (v), f being the focal length

Comment: $ m= v/u $ in either case. For spherical case focus will be lost in spherical aberration.

Comment: do you know the formula $1/f=1/u+1/v$ so just eliminate u or v with $1/u=1/f-1/v$ or $u=\frac{f*v}{v-f} $

Answer (score 0):

Consider the ray through the center of the lens (assumed thin). o and i are object and image distances; h and h' are object and image heights. From similar triangles, h'/i = h/o so h'/h = i/o.

[image: Thin lens ray diagram]